# Code samples for Django + SWFUpload?

Tags: python, django, swfupload

Does anyone have any simple code samples for Django + [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)? I have it working perfectly in my PHP application but Django is giving me headaches.

Comment: -1: No Code.  -1: No Error Traceback or other messages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't give you any very detailed code samples, but I have quite a bit of experience with working with SWFUpload + Django (for a photo sharing site I work on). Anyway, here are a few pointers that will hopefully help you on your quest for DjSWF happiness :)

1. You'll want to use the cookies plugin (if of course you are using some sort of session-based authentication [like `django.contrib.auth`, and care who uploaded what).

   The cookies plugin sends the data from cookies as POST, so you'll have to find some way of getting this back into `request.COOKIES` (`process_request` middleware that looks for a `settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` in `request.POST` on specific URLs and dumps it into `request.COOKIES` works nicely for this :)
2. Also, remember that you *must* return something in the response body for SWFUpload to recognize it as a successful upload attempt. I believe this has changed in the latest beta of SWFUpload, but anyway it's advisable just to stick something in there like 'ok'. For failures, make use of something like `HttpResponseBadRequest` or the like.
3. Lastly, in case you're having trouble finding them, the uploaded file is in `request.FILES` :)

If you have anything perplexing I haven't covered, feel free to post something more detailed and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: This is an excellent answer to a really terrible question.  The second paragraph of point (1) helped me in particular.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Django version of the samples for SWFUpload:

http://github.com/naltimari/django-swfupload-samples/tree/master

So long uploadify. Great idea but it is just buggy, especially on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my Django-specific implementation for fixing this issue (i.e. my uploads were failing in Firefox with a 302 Redirect).

In my initial view that generates the page with the uploader on it, I looked at the cookies and found sessionid

```
ipdb> self.request.COOKIES
{'csrftoken': '43535f552b7c94563ada784f4d469acf', 'sessionid': 'rii380947wteuevuus0i5nbvpc6qq7i1'}
```

When I looked at what was being posted in the SWFUploadMiddleware (when using Firefox), I found that the sessionid was not being set.

In my intial view that generates the page that contains the upload handler, I added the sessionid to the context.

```
context['sessionid'] = self.request.session.session_key
```

In my swfuploader settings, I added sessionid to the post-params option as follows:

```
post_params: {... "sessionid": "{{ sessionid }}" ...},
```

Now, when I looked in the SWFUploadMiddleware, I could see the sessionid being posted, **and my uploads started working if Firefox**.

```
ipdb> request.POST 
<QueryDict: {... u'session_id': [u'rii380947wteuevuus0i5nbvpc6qq7i1'],...}>
```

For completeness, my SWFUploadMiddleware looks like this...

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class SWFUploadMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if (request.method == 'POST') and (request.path == reverse('upload_handler')) and request.POST.has_key(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME):
            request.COOKIES[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME] = request.POST[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634666/403-forbidden-error-on-swfupload-and-django
    # Fix for problem uploading images (403 error) in Firefox 20 and others
    if request.POST.has_key('csrftoken'):
            request.COOKIES['csrftoken'] = request.POST['csrftoken']
```