# How to program multi file upload with Django jquery

Tags: jquery, django, file-upload

I need to program the system where user can select multiple files from the windows

1. User selects Multiple files with browser
2. The web page shows the all filenames in list
3. Then when user click on start upload
4. Then i see the progress bar in front of each file and also size in KB  showing how much has been uploaded . Like google basic file upload in google docs

Currently i know only how to upload single file with django but i have no idea how should i start with this

Answer (score 1):

For the jQuery upload part, you could use the uploadify plugin:

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Just my 2 cents. Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Plupload (http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php) is another option for a jQuery plugin to do multifile upload and has more active development. I've used both Uploadify and Plupload, both are nice, Plupload has more bells and whistles though and has things like HTML 5 drag/drop from desktop supported.

If you already do single file uploads your django page for handling these uploads shouldn't differ too much because as the uploaders go through the queue they will all make individual requests to your django script to handle an upload.

Helpful links:

http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/7195/uploadify-3.0-beta-with-django/p1

https://github.com/tstone/django-uploadify/wiki

[Code samples for Django + SWFUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612734/code-samples-for-django-swfupload/61289)

Comment: it says that it uses `upload.php` , but what should be the cotent of that from django point of view

Comment: I am not a django person myself but I've added some links that might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a couple of third-party solutions, and the easiest to integrate with django (especially if you're using jquery) is:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

You just write a simple ajax view to save the uploaded files.