# 403 Forbidden error on swfupload and django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, uploadify, swfupload

I'm trying to use a script for multiple file uploads, like swfupload or uploadify on my django application but no matter what I try, I always get a 403 forbidden error for the upload URL. If I try to run the 'same' code (just different links to same files) independently, it works like a charm.

Any idea if I'm missing something on my main code or is there some kind of setting that I don't know about?

Comment: It sounds like a permissions configuration issue to me. But you haven't really provided enough info to troubleshoot beyond that.

Comment: I didn't even know what to provide as information. Can you be specific to what kind of information do you need?

Comment: The problem is solved. It was a problem with CSRF protection as @Perchouli pointed out but I had to include @csrf_exempt before the function to remove CSRF protection for that particular function only.

Comment: If someone provided the correct answer, please accept that answer by clicking the check-mark icon next to it.

Comment: @ashvagan writing `@csrf_exempt` to your view doesn't solve your problem. You just made a security vulnerability.`CSRF` protection is used for a valid reason in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ .If you want to apply secure method, pelase apply my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally related with `CSRF protection`. In my case I solved that issue such that,

**views.py**

```
def photo_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         for field_name in request.FILES:
         ....
         ....
         return HttpResponse("ok", mimetype="text/plain")

    else:       
         return render_response(request, 'wpphotos/post/photo_upload.html', {"csrf_token": get_token(request)},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Because flash useses its own session while uploading, you should set `csrf_token` value in your middleware such that

**swfupload.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class SWFUploadMiddleware(object):

def process_request(self, request):
    if (request.method == 'POST') and (request.path == reverse('project_name.module_name.views.photo_upload')) and \
            request.POST.has_key(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME):
        request.COOKIES[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME] = request.POST[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]
    if request.POST.has_key('csrftoken'):           
        request.COOKIES['csrftoken'] = request.POST['csrftoken']
```

For the last step, you should set `csrftoken` as post parameter in your javascript for `SWFUpload` settings such that

**photo_upload.html**

```
window.onload = function() {
    swfupload = new SWFUpload({
        post_params: {
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{csrf_token}}"
        },
        upload_url: "/module_name/post/photo_upload/",
        flash_url: "/media/flash/swfupload.swf",
        file_size_limit : "2.5 MB",
                    ....
                    ....
                    ....
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

I use [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) in my django project, get 403 error too, because django has CSRF protection. so i change this function in my views.py solve this problem.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt    
@csrf_exempt
def ajax_flash_upload(request):
```

Comment: what did you change in your function?

Comment: 1.import csrf_exempt: `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`  2.use the csrf_protect decorator in my function `@csrf_exempt`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the [flash cookie bug](http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/383): your client has an authentication cookie that the flash is not including in its request to the server. Since the request doesn't have the auth cookie, it gets rejected with a 403.

Comment: well, it doesn't work on IE either and gives the same error. So it seems out of question for now.

Comment: are you sure the request performed by the flash to your controller has the needed cookie info? You should compare the cookies of the other requests that work to the flash ones.

Comment: The code is working when I use it as a stand alone project. But when I integrate it with my project, it starts giving the 403 forbidden error. I have compared the settings.py file but I couldn't find anything that may be blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra data when initializing Uploadify (make your changes on "swf" and "uploader" settings):

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData' : { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : '{{csrf_token}}' },
            'swf'       : '/static/js/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader'  : '{% url upload %}',
            // Put your other options here
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, brsbilgic. I've tried your solution, and it worked!
By the way, the middleware snippet should be modified to:

```
if request.POST.has_key('csrfmiddlewaretoken'):           
    request.COOKIES['csrftoken'] = request.POST['csrfmiddlewaretoken']
```